# Does moving after becoming hidden stop the enemy from being flat footed for the purposes of a sneak attack?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, sneak-attack

If I hide successfully the rulebook says that the enemy is flat-footed for an attack. But let's say the enemy is 10 ft away so that I would first go to it.

Action: Hide
Action: Move
Action: Attack

Would I lose my flat-footed advantage?

Comment: Note that there are also some feats that allow you to remain hidden after certain actions, perhaps most notably the rogue feat Spring from the Shadows, which gives you a full Stride before Striking and maintains hidden/undetected until the Strike.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Hide](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=62) action has that:

> If you successfully become hidden to a creature but then cease to have cover or greater cover against it or be concealed from it, you become observed again. You cease being hidden if you do anything except Hide, Sneak, or Step.

So if you move using a [Sneak](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=63) or [Step](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=87) action and have **cover or concealment from them at the end of your movement** (right next to them), then you would still be hidden and they would still be flat-footed to your attack.

Good ways to do this include fog/smoke or invisibility, though it may be better to just use a ranged attack in this situation.

Comment: I'd recommend bolding "cover or concealment from them at the end of your movement" just to draw attention to that being the key factor

Answer (score 0):

Once you've become hidden, sneakng is the actual movement form that you would take. Page 252 of the Core reads,

> You're undetected by the creature during your movement and remain
> undetected by the creature at the end of it.

Since you're still hidden 'at the end' of your movement, your target is still flat-footed when you attack.